# How to solve equation in complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

For $n$ odd ( e.g. with $n\equiv 1\mod 4 )$ I seek a solution $f(n)$ for this simple equation
in the complex numbers
$$(-1)^{f(n)}2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=-\frac i2(1+i)^{n+1}$$
$f(n)$ is probably an integer valued funcion.

As I suppose it will be helpful to change into exponential representation and then take logarithm - but I am not firm about multivaluedness.

Comment: $f(n)$ is not integer-valued generally, for $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, the right hand side is purely imaginary, and so $f(n)\in \frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z}$ then. Writing the right hand side in polar form gives you $f(n)$ quickly.

Comment: Sorry. My formulation was not good. If not $n\equiv 1\mod 4$ my corresponding problem is with this right hand side $-i(1+i)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$(-1)^{f(n)} = -i \frac{(1+i)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2}^{n+1}}$$

Note that:

$$(1+i) = \sqrt{2}·e^{\large i\pi/4}$$

Therefore:

$$(-1)^{f(n)} = -i·e^{\large(n+1)i\pi/4}$$

Since $-i = e^{\large -i\pi/2}$ and $-1 = e^{\large i\pi}$

Then we want:

$$e^{\large i\pi ·f(n)} = e^{\large(n-1)i\pi/4}$$

So choosing $f(n) = \frac{n-1}{4}$ would work.

Note that since $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ then $f(n)$ is indeed an integer valued function.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(n)$ is indeed integer valued, then $(-1)^{f(n)} \in \{-1,1\}$. If $f(n)$ is a solution, then all $f(n) + 2k\ \ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are solutions, as well. The fact that the equation is of complex nature, doesn't change that. So for every n, you basically have only two possible solutions: $f(n)$ even or odd.

Comment: Thats right. But I sought a formula which I could use with a computer for instance. So the solution of DartGeek is what I was looking for.